# How to restore an iPhone backup from an external hard drive (windows)

Tags: iphone, itunes, hard-drive, backup, restore

I backed up my phone on itunes and it took a lot of space on my laptop so I put the backup on an external drive, however, not knowing any better, I did not create any symlink.
Is there any way I can restore the backup to my new phone from the external drive?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm assuming in light of [your other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339841/how-to-restore-backup-from-external-drive-to-itunes-or-iphone-in-windows-8), that what you're asking here is for a way to do this without using iTunes? Or are you asking something else? You'll need to differentiate this from your other question.

Comment: Apologies, what i’m Asking is. Is there a way to still restore the  back up from the external drive. Is there any way I can “let iTunes know” where the backup folder is? I do have the backup folder on the hard drive and can move it back to the computer, however iTunes is not finding it when I try to restore a backup.